# Advanced filter does not equal to a list of IDs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of IDs from range A1, A2 and so on (Including Header in range A1) which I want the code to exclude while filtering the data from another workbook.

My criteria range is B25:G26. I tried using <>ID by the pasting this in Range B26 (B25 as the header), which ran fine just for a single ID but does not work for the entire list.

What formula should I type in Range B26 so that the code understands that it should exclude the IDs in rangeA1, A2 and so on?

Could anyone please help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Sheet2!Z2 as the first ID cell in the data you want to filter, use:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!Z2,$A$1:$A$10,0))
```

Comment: The data set is in another workbook and the first ID cell is A8. So how do I include that in the formula? Also, I don't want this to work specifically to one file as the code will filter data from different file as well.

Comment: It would be `=ISERROR(MATCH('[book name.xlsx]Sheetname'!A8,$A$1:$A$10,0))`. Your code can adjust/recreate the formula using the relevant ranges.

Comment: Is it possible to select the sheet no. instead of Sheet Name?

Comment: You need the name for the formula, but your code can work that out.